# Error handling with MonadPlus

Tags: haskell, monads, monadplus

Got stuck again while trying to learn some Haskell. What I'm trying to do is implementing a combined `head/tail` method for lists with error handling. The signature must look like this:

```
head' :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> m (a,[a])
```

However I'm a bit lost at how error handling with MonadPlus works. I tried the following:

```
head' xs = if (length xs > 0) then Just(head xs, tail xs) else Nothing
```

but it complains: Expected type: m (a, [a]) Actual type: Maybe (a, [a]). Just for fun I also tried:

```
head' xs = if (length xs > 0) then Just(head xs, tail xs) else Nothing `mplus` Nothing
```

but not only does that look redundant, it also does not work either.

Any hints appreciated!

Comment: Maybe is one possible MonadPlus, there are many others. If you want to work with any possible MonadPlus, don't use Maybe functions, they are too specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
head' :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> m (a,[a])
head' xs = if null xs then mzero then return (head xs, tail xs)
```

`mzero` is the "nothing" or (indeed) "zero" value, which you can use here to model the absence of a result. It has type `m x` for any type `x` and monad with zero `m`, so it fits here.

Instead, `return` wraps any value in any monad. In particular, you can insert our `(a,[a])` pair inside `m`. (This does not even require the monad to be a `MonadPlus`)

Note how in the code above we did not mention any specific monad: the code is indeed generic, so that it can work with any `MonadPlus`.

Lastly, I used `null` instead of `length ... > 0` since `null` only examines the first constructor in the list, while `length ... > 0` has to traverse it all.

You can actually remove the check by switching to pattern matching:

```
head' :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> m (a,[a])
head' []     = mzero
head' (x:xs) = return (x, xs)
```

Comment: After I fixed the error in the above if-statement, the code compiled. However, when trying to run it, e.g. by calling `head' []`, I get:
No instance for (MonadPlus m0) arising from a use of 'it'
 The type variable 'm0' is ambiguous
 Note: there are several potential instances:
   instance MonadPlus Maybe -- Defined in 'Control.Monad'
   instance MonadPlus [] -- Defined in 'Control.Monad'
 In the first argument of 'print', namely 'it'

Comment: @Marco When you use a polymorphic type, you have to specify the concrete type at which you want to use it. This is done e.g. by writing `head' [] :: Maybe (Int, [Int])` or by using it in a suitable context e.g. `f (head' [])` where `f` has type `Maybe (Int,[Int]) -> ...`. Of course, instead of `Maybe` you can use any other `MonadPlus`, and instead of `Int` anything else. The same issue is found with `read "32"`, for instance.